# 14 Days given for a revision in Scientific Reports

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, deadlines

I wanted to know if giving a deadline of 14 days for a revision is normal for a journal like Scientific Reports? In my decision letter, the reviewers have called my work novel.

Comment: That's really short! If it's only minor revision might be acceptable but definitely not for major revisions or something more involved.

Comment: Just ask for an extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't say anything about Scientific Reports specifically, but yes I've been getting shorter deadlines recently for journals. I think journals see "time to publish" as a marketable metric, so they're trying to speed things up (see e.g. https://www.nature.com/nature-portfolio/about/journal-metrics ).

When my group has had a lot of things going on or when we know revisions are likely to take longer than the time given, we've always been granted more time when we request it, it's not really a big deal to request more time.

> In my decision letter, the reviewers have called my work novel.

This is irrelevant to time given to make revisions or anything. Note that Scientific Reports is pretty much an "accept everything" journal; they filter out some junk but they do not reject based on perceived impact or novelty.